# Do I have more overview if I program it this way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I started learning Reactjs and I would like to know the best practise. I have the following pages :
-Home
-BMICalculator
-Etc

My question is, should all my logic i.e 'calculateBmi' be in my Bmi.js? Or should I put them in my App.js file?

What would be the best practise for this? Because when I make more little projects, the App.js file would contain lots of different functions.

I think the best practise is to put all the functions in the Bmi.js. But what is your opinion? I just started learning Reactjs.

App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/layout/Header';
import Homepage from './components/Homepage';

import Bmi from './components/bmiCalculator/Bmi';
import CalculateBmi from './components/bmiCalculator/CalculateBmi';


class App extends Component {

  calculateBmi = (length, weight) => {

    const lengthInMeters = length / 100;
    const bmi = weight / (lengthInMeters * lengthInMeters);

    console.log(bmi);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Header />
          <Route exact path="/" render={props => (
            <React.Fragment>
              <Homepage />
            </React.Fragment>
          )} />

          <Route path="/bmicalculator" render={props => (
            <React.Fragment>
              <Bmi calculateBmi={this.calculateBmi} />
            </React.Fragment>
          )} />
        </div>
      </Router>

    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

Bmi.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Bmi extends Component {

    state = {
        length: '',
        weight: ''
    }

    onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.calculateBmi(this.state.length, this.state.weight);
        this.setState({ length: '' });

    }

    onChange = (e) => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="bmiborder">
                <h1 style={titleStyle}>BMI Healthy Weight Calculator</h1>
                <div style={resultStyle} className="bmiResultContainer">
                    <p>Body Mass Index(BMI) = 20.9</p>
                    <p>Normal weight</p>
                </div>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <div className="background">
                        <div className="inputGroup">
                            Length (cm)<input type="number" name="length" placeholder="180" value={this.state.length} onChange={this.onChange}></input>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="background">
                        <div className="inputGroup">
                            Weight (kg)<input type="number" name="weight" placeholder="75" value={this.state.weight} onChange={this.onChange}  ></input>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="background">
                        <div className="inputGroup">
                            <input type="submit" value="Calculate" style={buttonStyle}></input>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div >

        )
    }

}



const titleStyle = {
    color: "White"
}

const resultStyle = {
    margin: "0",
    padding: "0"
}

const buttonStyle = {
    backgroundColor: "#ff4081",
    color: "white",
    border: "none",
    width: "150px",
    height: "36px",
    borderRadius: "3px",
    cursor: "pointer",
}

export default Bmi;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your methods should be placed as low as possible i.e. in components they literally concern to i.e. in this case in Bmi.js

Also I'd consider separating domain logic and presentation ( with corresponding domain and ui stores ) that way you'll end up with an architecture you can reuse for web and mobile versions for example.

Comment: So my calculateBmi method should be under de render() method right?

Answer (score 1):

This is already fine but unless no other components would be sharing the `calculateBmi` function, you could move that also into the `BMI` component.

Let's say you have another component that would use the valued returned from `calculateBMi` then it would be okay to keep it in the main `App` component. Otherwise, the pattern of separation of concern is always the best practice.

So your `App` component will not have state and can be refactored into a simple stateless function.

so now you would have something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/layout/Header';
import Homepage from './components/Homepage';

import Bmi from './components/bmiCalculator/Bmi';


const App = () => {  
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Header />
          <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />

          <Route path="/bmicalculator" component={Bmi} />
        </div>
      </Router>

    );
}
```

AND

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CalculateBmi from './components/bmiCalculator/CalculateBmi';

export class Bmi extends Component {

    state = {
        length: '',
        weight: ''
    }
    calculateBmi = (length, weight) => {

       const lengthInMeters = length / 100;
       const bmi = weight / (lengthInMeters * lengthInMeters);

       console.log(bmi);
    }

    onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.calculateBmi(this.state.length, this.state.weight);
        this.setState({ length: '' });

    }

    onChange = (e) => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="bmiborder">
                <h1 style={titleStyle}>BMI Healthy Weight Calculator</h1>
                <div style={resultStyle} className="bmiResultContainer">
                    <p>Body Mass Index(BMI) = 20.9</p>
                    <p>Normal weight</p>
                </div>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <div className="background">
                        <div className="inputGroup">
                            Length (cm)<input type="number" name="length" placeholder="180" value={this.state.length} onChange={this.onChange}></input>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="background">
                        <div className="inputGroup">
                            Weight (kg)<input type="number" name="weight" placeholder="75" value={this.state.weight} onChange={this.onChange}  ></input>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="background">
                        <div className="inputGroup">
                            <input type="submit" value="Calculate" style={buttonStyle}></input>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div >

        )
    }

}



const titleStyle = {
    color: "White"
}

const resultStyle = {
    margin: "0",
    padding: "0"
}

const buttonStyle = {
    backgroundColor: "#ff4081",
    color: "white",
    border: "none",
    width: "150px",
    height: "36px",
    borderRadius: "3px",
    cursor: "pointer",
}

export default Bmi;
```

This way you would have achieved separation of presentational components from stateful/data-driven components. This should facilitate component reuse and present you with a much more scalable architecture, thus you can use the `BMI` component everywhere within your application and if you need to make changes to you `BMI` you can freely do so at one place in the `BMI` component. Without having to pass the `calculateBMI` props all the time in the app component

Comment: Ah oki thanks. No I don't use the bmi in any other file. But I did not do anything with calculateBmi.js yet. I did not know if it was usefull to have a seperate file to calculate the bmi. Because I can do the calculation in the same file (bmi.js)

Comment: Yeah, so I realized I made a mistake in the code I shared above... you can have the `calculateBmi()` inside of the BMI class. i have made an edit to the code. it's fairly simple to do the calculation inside the component like you're saying. Don't worry it's good practice.